# Retrofit call to Spotify API returns a 404 error

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, spotify

Am using retrofit2 to try to connect to Spotify. For now I am just logging the result code to see if it works. When I remove the "Authorization" Header/Parameter from my api call, it gives me a 401 error, indicating that I was not authorized. When I add the Authorization parameter and pass the access token, it gives me 404 error, indicating "not found". I am inexperienced with this stuff, but nonetheless this confuses me, please send thoughts/suggestions.

```
import static com.example.spotifyapp1.spotifyconstants.Constants.CLIENT_ID;
import static com.example.spotifyapp1.spotifyconstants.Constants.REDIRECT_URI;
import static com.example.spotifyapp1.spotifyconstants.Constants.REQUEST_CODE;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.spotifyapp1.data.RetrofitInstance;
import com.example.spotifyapp1.data.SpotifyApi;
import com.example.spotifyapp1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.AuthorizationClient;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.AuthorizationRequest;
import com.spotify.sdk.android.auth.AuthorizationResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance();
    SpotifyApi spotifyApi = retrofit.create(SpotifyApi.class);

    Call<Response<String>> mainCall;

    String accessToken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);


        AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.TOKEN, REDIRECT_URI);

        AuthorizationRequest request = builder.setScopes(new String[]{"app-remote-control","streaming"}).build();
        AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(this,REQUEST_CODE,request);


        binding.setVolumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainCall.enqueue(
                        new Callback<Response<String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<Response<String>> call, Response<Response<String>> response) {
                                //Log.d("MainActivity",String.format("tokenAtCall:%s",accessToken));
                                Log.d("MainActivity", String.format("onResponse: code..%d",response.code()));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<Response<String>> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure");
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,intent);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(resultCode,intent);

            switch (response.getType()) {
                case TOKEN:
                    //Log.d("MainActivity", "token");
                    accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
                    //Log.d("MainActivity",String.format("token:%s",accessToken));
                    mainCall = spotifyApi.setVolume("Bearer " + accessToken,50,null);

                case ERROR:
                    //Log.d("MainActivity", "error");

                default:
                    //Log.d("MainActivity", "default");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I use the spotify.android:auth library to authenticate with spotify. The authentication appears to work as it provides me with an access token, which I then attempt to pass into the call, unsuccessfully.

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.PUT;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface SpotifyApi {

    @PUT("/me/player/volume")
    Call<Response<String>> setVolume(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Query("volume_percent") int volumePercent,
        @Query("device_id") String deviceId
    );

}
```

Here's my api

```
import static com.example.spotifyapp1.spotifyconstants.Constants.BASE_URL;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitInstance {

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit;

    }

}
```

and my retrofit

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! The "/v1" part of the URL needed to be on the endpoint rather than in the base URL, despite the documentation seemingly stating otherwise. Confusing and frustrating!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).